# Wrong wsdl URL in webservice.asmx?disco when proxy is use

Tags: c#, web-services

My application is running on a Windows server in the intra net. Application URL is like this: **win_serv/APP_DIR/**. And webserwice.asmx URL is a "win_serv/APP_DIR/webservice.asmx"

Public application URL is like this: **app.domain.com (APP_DOMAIN)** and public Webservice.asmx URL is like this **APP_DOMAIN/webservice.asmx**.

In this configuration auto generated discovery XML (APP_DOMAIN/webservice.asmx?disco) is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<discovery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/">
  <contractRef ref="http://APP_DOMAIN/APP_DIR/webservice.asmx?wsdl" docRef="http://APP_DOMAIN/APP_DIR/webservice.asmx" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/" />
  <soap address="http://APP_DOMAIN/APP_DIR/webservice.asmx" xmlns:q1="http://NAMESPACE/" binding="q1:WebServiceSoap" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/soap/" />
  <soap address="http://APP_DOMAIN/APP_DIR/webservice.asmx" xmlns:q2="http://NAMESPACE/" binding="q2:WebServiceSoap12" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/soap/" />
</discovery>
```

So I used class SoapExtensionReflector:

```
public override void ReflectDescription()
  {
     ServiceDescription description = ReflectionContext.ServiceDescription;

     foreach (Service service in description.Services)
     {
        foreach (Port port in service.Ports)
        {
           foreach (ServiceDescriptionFormatExtension extension in port.Extensions)
           {
              SoapAddressBinding binding = extension as SoapAddressBinding;

              if (null != binding)
              {
                 binding.Location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SoapAddress"]; //http://APP_DOMAIN/webservice.asmx
              }
           }
        }
     }
}
```

But this solution fixes only soap address is valid (**http://APP_DOMAIN/webservice.asmx**). WSDL URL is still invalid (**http://APP_DOMAIN/APP_DIR/webservice.asmx?wsdl**). Discovery looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<discovery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/">
  <contractRef ref="http://APP_DOMAIN/APP_DIR/webservice.asmx?wsdl" docRef="http://APP_DOMAIN/APP_DIR/webservice.asmx" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/" />
  <soap address="http://APP_DOMAIN/webservice.asmx" xmlns:q1="http://NAMESPACE/" binding="q1:WebServiceSoap" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/soap/" />
  <soap address="http://APP_DOMAIN/webservice.asmx" xmlns:q2="http://NAMESPACE/" binding="q2:WebServiceSoap12" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/soap/" />
</discovery>
```

How to fix wsdl URL?

p.s. sorry for my english